# IIS 7.5 HTTP Redirect thru Web.config

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, web.config-transform

I am redirecting one domain to another domain using HTTP Direct but I would like to forward all requests except one request with hb.txt file in that folder. How can I modify my web.config to add that exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.xxxxx.com$S?$P" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```